# Как запустить процесс в теле родительского процесса: как внедрить код программы которая уже скомпилирована и имеет расширение .exe?

Tags: c++, windows, процесс

Здравствуйте, назрел вопрос как запустить программу через c++ процесс которой будет находиться в процессе родительской программы (находится в процессе программы которой её запустила). И должна быть возможность в последствии закрыть этот процесс. Увидел данную возможность при просмотре функций скрытого майнера, а для меня это был бы хороший опыт.

Comment: Извините не так был задан вопрос, сейчас его переформулирую и отправлю вопрос еще раз.

Comment: Процесс в процессе? Вроде в винде так не бывает. Можно внедрить код, но это не приведет к появлению нового процесса.

Comment: Именно, мне и надо сделать так, чтобы не создовалось нового процесса. Только вот как внедрить код программы которая уже скомпилирована и имеет расширение .exe?

Comment: @Abyx нет никакого смысла. EXE инжектится на раз, как и "просто код" без MZPE-заголовков.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Внедрение своего кода в чужой процесс - инжект и это очень плохо. Но если очень надо - `WriteProcessMemory()` для начала определенно то что нужно. Более навороченные техники инжекта (да и детали вышеуказанного), IMHO, как потенциально вредоносные тут обсуждать не стоит.

Comment: Слушай спасибо тебе за то что ты помог, но все же я еще новичок и только в этом разбираюсь, если тебе не сложно мог бы ты дать кусочек кода и объяснить как он работает, желательно по простому. Заранее спасибо

Comment: @Aleksei.C читайте MSDN, там нужные API описаны.